# Type error detailed view django

Tags: python, django

Hello I get an type error (takes 2 arguments but only 1 given.) in /taskoftheday.

I don't know what I should do to fix it. What argument am I missing?
I want the create a detailed view for each guide ID.

Here is my code:

Views:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Guide, Step, Sub_step


def taskoftheday(request, guide_id):
    try:
        guide = Guide.objects.get(pk=guide_id)
    except Guide.DoesNotExst:
        raise Http404("Guide does not exist")
    return render(request, 'taskoftheday/taskoftheday.html', {'guide': guide})


def detail_taskoftheday(request):
    return render(render, 'taskoftheday/detail_taskoftheday.html')
```

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.taskoftheday, name="taskoftheday"),
    url(r'(?P<guide_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail_taskoftheday, name='detail_taskoftheday'),
]
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the view names `taskoftheday` and `detail_taskoftheday` juxtaposed in your `views.py`.

`taskoftheday` should take a sole argument - `request` - while `detail_taskoftheday` should take both `request` and `guide_id`:

```
def detail_taskoftheday(request, guide_id):
    try:
        guide = Guide.objects.get(pk=guide_id)
    except Guide.DoesNotExst:
        raise Http404("Guide does not exist")
    return render(request, 'taskoftheday/detail_taskoftheday.html', {'guide': guide})

def taskoftheday(request):
    return render(render, 'taskoftheday/taskoftheday.html')
```

Comment: Okey thanks! I have remade it now but face another issue. I wanna use the taskoftheday function to show a guide directly like a detailed view. How do i do this?